# Why HP-LoadRunner or any Performance Testing Tool not clears sessions while execution

Tags: session, performance-testing, loadrunner

While doing Performance Testing Execution using Load-Runner or any other Performance Testing tool we select "clear cache on each iteration" 
It does not clear sessions on each iterations.

my Scenario is separate
1- Login
2- Action
3- End

Same thing if we do on UI, For Example: 
logged on - perform 1 or 2 transaction and clear cache, It will land-up on Login page again.

Why tool don't clears session what is the funda behind that.

Comment: You are confusing cache, which applies to downloaded items, to session and state, which is stored in memory.  You are also confusing the default behavior of your web site when you clear the session variables from the client browser with what happens when you start a new user iteration (new session) in a performance testing tool.   #architecturematters

Comment: You can try `web_cleanup_cookies()` for this purpose.